# Android unrequested ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-permissions, facebook-sdk-4.0, flurry-analytics

I noticed that during my application's install, it requests "approximate location (network-based)" permission. I haven't asked for ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION in the manifest, but I'm using three SDKs which are the only suspects.

The SDKs in use are: Facebook, Flurry and Parse.

The declared permissions in the manifest are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

How can I find out who is asking for ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission?

Flurry docs mention that ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION is an optional permission, but nothing said about ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION.(https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/gettingstarted/android/)

I couldn't find info regarding Facebook and Parse network related permissions.

Comment: Look for a manifest merger report in the `build/` directory tree inside your `app/` module, if you are using Android Studio.

Comment: OK, found the merged manifest and it has: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>`. But who asked for that permission? Facebook, Flurry or Parse SDK?

Comment: I wasn't referring to the merged manifest itself, but the manifest merger report. For a `debug` build, it will be named `manifest-merger-debug-report.txt`. It used to be in `build/outputs/apk/` of your module, but I have this nagging feeling that it moved recently. That report, while obtuse, should give you some clues as to who asked for that permission.

Comment: Sorry, my misunderstanding. You solved the problem! Kudos! The report exists in app\build\outputs\logs. And this is what I found: `uses-permission#android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
ADDED from com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0:23:5
MERGED from com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps...`

Comment: CommonsWare, Salute to you!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have a permission from third-party dependencies, easiest way is declaring in your manifest all permissions with "remove" tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" tools:node="remove"/>
```